# Even using the simple example on the site my submit button doesn't send

Tags: html, form-submit

My Formsubmit doesn't work.
Even using the simple example on the site my submit button doesn't send. I can't even send the verification to my email.

I'm using Angular.

```
<form action="https://formsubmit.co/matheusproencaescola@hotmail.com" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="name" required>
      <input type="email" name="email" required>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
 </form>
```

EDIT: he problem is the button seems to have no function, it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a little late, but try this:

```
<form #form action="https://formsubmit.co/matheusproencaescola@hotmail.com" method='POST'>
    <input type="text" name="name" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" required>
    <button type="submit" (click)="form.submit()">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try replace

```
<button type="submit">Send</button>
```

by:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
```

Complete Code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="https://formsubmit.co/matheusproencaescola@hotmail.com" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="name" required/>
            <input type="email" name="email" required/>
            <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edited: Right! I used button tag and it works too.

When I click on button, it redirects to:
https://formsubmit.co/matheusproencaescola@hotmail.com

What happen in your case ?

Comment: the same mistake

Comment: Sou br tb, só não sei se podemos conversar em pt aqui por que não estamos no overflow pt
Mas cara, meu botão de send n acontece nada, é como ele n tivesse a função enviar

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).